# Cannot Create InboxRule on one individual mailbox

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, powershell

This one user when trying to create a rule through outlook throws the generic "One or more rules cannot be uploaded to Microsoft Exchange and have been deactivated.  This could be because some of the parameters are not supported, or there is insufficient space to store all of your rules"

This user does not have any other rules set, i've adjusted the rule quota to the max value.

When I try to create a rule using the powershell cmdlet New-InboxRule, I get the following error (The command works for multiple other mailboxes on the same database, as well for other users) :

```
There was an error saving the rules.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [New-InboxRule], StoragePermanentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 569675E6,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewInboxRule
```

Comment: Have you already tried running `outlook.exe /cleanrules" on the client?

Comment: Yes, i've also piped get-inboxrule in remove-inboxrule

Comment: Do you have the ability to move the mailbox to a temporary database and then back to its existing one?  That would probably clean up the issue, but I'm just speculating since I've never seen this issue.

Comment: What parameters are you using with the `New-InboxRule`? Is this a 2010-only organizations or do you have other versions of Exchange Server installed?

Comment: The mailbox move failed with the following error:

   8/26/2013 5:12:34 PM [CASSERVER] Fatal error MapiExceptionBadValue has occurred.
Error details: MapiExceptionBadValue: Unable to synchronize manifest. (hr=0x80040301, ec=-2147220735)

Comment: 2010-only Update Rollup 6 for Exchange Server 2010 SP2   14.2.342.3 for all servers.

Comment: seeing this as well in the event log with the same ec number

    Service MSExchangeMailboxAssistants. An exception has been handled on behalf of an assistant. A report will be sent for the following exception: Microsoft.Exchange.Assistants.AIGrayException ---> Microsoft.Exchange.Common.GrayException ---> Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionBadValue: MapiExceptionBadValue: Unable to modify table. (hr=0x80040301, ec=-2147220735)
Diagnostic context:

Comment: Sounds like mailbox corruption. If the mailbox won't move, can you do a new-mailboxexportrequest, or export to a PST from within Outlook and then recreate the mailbox?

Comment: We ended up having to disable/delete and recreate the mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up having to backup all mail/calendar/contacts into a pst then disable / delete the mailbox in question, recreate the mailbox and re-import all of the data.